# How do we get the current page URL in Lift snippets?

Tags: scala, lift

How do we get the current page URL in Lift snippets? I am trying to figure out if the current request is in SSL (http or https).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't specify the version of Lift you're using, but there are a couple of options. In very recent versions you can use [`CurrentReq`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/net/liftweb/http/CurrentReq$.html):

```
import net.liftweb.http.CurrentReq

val secure = CurrentReq.value.request.scheme == "https"
```

Another option is `S`'s `request` method:

```
import net.liftweb.http.S

val secure = S.request.map(_.request.scheme == "https").openOr(false)
```

You could retrieve the rest of the page URL using other methods on [`HTTPRequest`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/net/liftweb/http/provider/HTTPRequest.html).

Comment: I do not have CurrentReq  in my version of lift. In the end, I am using the following code:
S.request.map(_.request.isSecure).openOr(false)

Comment: One problem with CurrentReq is that if used in an AJAX callback it will return the path of the Ajax call, not the resource (i.e. page) on which the callback occurred. For that, use `S.originalRequest`.